# What is a decoy-server?

Tags: server, honeypot

I see that the term "decoy-server" is often used but I am not able to find a more formal definition for it. Can someone help?

E.g
https://scholar.google.com.sg/scholar?hl=en&q=%22decoy+server%22&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=

Comment: Maybe someone could also explain the difference between a decoy server and public server?

Comment: What do you mean by "well" used? You mean used often?

Comment: @d1str0 yes, the term is often used.

Comment: Can you provide an example of it's usage? Context may make a difference.

Comment: Sure: see here when it is mentioned in the context. https://scholar.google.com.sg/scholar?hl=en&q=%22decoy+server%22&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honey-pot. Attractive nuisance server that can be used to monitor attacks.

And a decoy/honeypot is a public server if it's accessible by the public as opposed to being an internal tool in an IPS (Intrusion Prevention System).

All servers accessible by the public are public servers, not all decoy servers are accessible by the public.

[More definitive explanation from SANS.](http://www.sans.org/security-resources/idfaq/honeypot3.php)

Comment: So, a decoy server is a honey-pot?

Comment: Yep, another term for it is man-trap. As to what it does, that's dependent on what you are trying to do. It is named to sound important, equipped with services that appear to be vital and can be used to trap hacking attempts, monitor hacking attempts to see what techniques and which services are being targetted.